# implement actionsheet in android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement the action sheet in android. This feature is not present and I'm wondering, if anyone has come across this feature? I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

upto my understanding i think u are trying to implement [ContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html) here is an [example](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/04/android-context-menu-example-on-long-press-gridview/)...

Comment: Thanks Adhavan, this should help me get up to speed!!