# How to implement actionsheet in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [implement actionsheet in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342180/implement-actionsheet-in-android)

I am trying to implement the action sheet in Android. This feature is not present and I'm wondering, if anyone has come across this feature?  I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope thse links help u,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html

http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/04/android-context-menu-example-on-long-press-gridview/

Comment: hi raghu i think cotext menu appear on button long press ,can we show context menu without button long press means if i  navigate from one activity to other context menu appear self on next screen?...thanks

Comment: Yes u can, Registering a context menu is when you want to allow the user to open it by long clicking. If you want to open it programmatically, you simply have to call openContextMenu. As for obtaining the view, you can either use findViewById if you gave it an id or save it as an attribute in your Activity class.

Comment: i think problem is clear to u ,actually i want to display context menu automatically with out long clicking on button..

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.app.Activity.registerForContextMenu(Activity.java:2343)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at soap.sdjfh.dj.attachreceipts.onCreate(attachreceipts.java:21)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java

Comment: have u created the Id for that menu, as ur passing null value so its showing that,check that once